Pyomo- adding in export limitation constraints into pyomo optimization for battery energy storage optimization model
I've been bashing my head up against a wall trying to add additional constraints into the battery energy flow model:
https://github.com/cwkcodes/lockbox/tree/7943fb664e808c0ba1bcb11a81f6180b34e1a623/BESS_Model
The file is under: BESS_Export_limit_test.ipynb
I want to have an EXPORT_CAPACITY var in kw which for each time step as it in 30 minute increments would be.
m.exportLimit = en.Param(initialize=-EXPORT_CAPACITY*TIME_STEP_HOURS)

It is negative as the export is returned as the negative net values from load-pv
def E_neg_net_rule(m, t):
        return m.negNetLoad[t] == m.negLoad[t] + m.posEInPV[t] + m.negEOutExport[t]
    m.E_negNet_cons = en.Constraint(m.Time, rule=E_neg_net_rule)

and
m.negEOutExport[t]

represent the export directly from the generation and export from the battery.
The export limit will apply to both of these they share an export limit.
An example would be if the user sets the export limit to 100kw then at every timestep the maximum export at any timestep between both the m.negNetLoad[t] and m.negEOutExport[t] would be -50kw.
The model currently works in its state but I require this functionality, thank you!
I'll supply the complete code here and a link to the github repo.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pyomo.environ as en
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
from assests.battery import Battery
import time
import logging

# Set up seaborn style
sns.set_style({
    'axes.linewidth': 1, 'axes.edgecolor': 'black',
    'xtick.direction': 'out', 'xtick.major.size': 4.0,
    'ytick.direction': 'out', 'ytick.major.size': 4.0,
    'axes.facecolor': 'white', 'grid.color': '.8',
    'grid.linestyle': '-', 'grid.linewidth': 0.5
})

# Setup logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# Constants
TIME_STEP_HOURS = 0.5
BIG_M = 500000

# Battery Parameters
Bcapacity = 300  # kWh
Bcharging_power = 75  # kW
Bdischarging_power = -75  # kW
Bcharging_efficiency = 0.95
Bdischarging_efficiency = 0.95
Bmin_soc = 0.5
Bmax_soc = 0.97
Binitial_soc = Bcapacity * Bmin_soc

# Create an instance of the Battery class
battery = Battery(
    capacity=Bcapacity,
    charging_power_limit=Bcharging_power,
    discharging_power_limit=Bdischarging_power,
    charging_efficiency=Bcharging_efficiency,
    discharging_efficiency=Bdischarging_efficiency,
    min_depth_of_discharge=Bmin_soc,
    max_depth_of_discharge=Bmax_soc
)

# Print battery parameters
logging.info(battery.get_parameters())

# Load test data
input_file_path = './input_data/BESS_Input.csv'
try:
    testData = pd.read_csv(input_file_path, parse_dates=['timestamp'], index_col='timestamp')
    logging.info(f"Loaded data from {input_file_path}")
except FileNotFoundError:
    logging.error(f"File not found: {input_file_path}")
    raise

# Ensure the index is a DateTimeIndex with the correct format
date_format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"
g_df = testData.copy()
g_df.index = pd.to_datetime(g_df.index, format=date_format, dayfirst=True)

def run_monthly_optimization(start_date, end_date, initial_soc):
    """
    Run optimization for a given month.

    Parameters:
    - start_date: pd.Timestamp, start of the optimization period
    - end_date: pd.Timestamp, end of the optimization period
    - initial_soc: float, initial state of charge of the battery

    Returns:
    - outputVars: np.array, optimization results
    - final_soc: float, final state of charge of the battery
    - cost_without_batt: float, cost without battery
    - cost_with_batt: float, cost with battery
    - score: float, optimization score
    - money_saved: float, money saved/earned
    """
    # month_data = g_df.loc[start_date:end_date].copy()
    # month_data['demand'] = month_data['demand'].shift(-1)
    # month_data['generation'] = month_data['generation'].shift(-1)

    month_data = g_df.loc[start_date:end_date].copy()
    month_data['demand'] = month_data['demand']
    month_data['generation'] = month_data['generation']

    # load = month_data['demand'].values[:-1]
    # PV = month_data['generation'].values[:-1]
    # sellPrice = month_data['sellPrice'].values[:-1]
    # buyPrice = month_data['buyPrice'].values[:-1]

    load = month_data['demand'].values
    PV = month_data['generation'].values
    sellPrice = month_data['sellPrice'].values
    buyPrice = month_data['buyPrice'].values

    priceDict1 = dict(enumerate(sellPrice))
    priceDict2 = dict(enumerate(buyPrice))
    net = load - PV
    posLoad = np.clip(net, a_min=0, a_max=None)
    negLoad = np.clip(net, a_min=None, a_max=0)
    posLoadDict = dict(enumerate(posLoad))
    negLoadDict = dict(enumerate(negLoad))

    m = en.ConcreteModel()
    m.Time = en.RangeSet(0, len(net) - 1)

    m.SOC = en.Var(m.Time, bounds=(battery.min_depth_of_discharge, battery.max_depth_of_discharge), initialize=initial_soc)
    m.posDeltaSOC = en.Var(m.Time, initialize=0)
    m.negDeltaSOC = en.Var(m.Time, initialize=0)
    m.posEInGrid = en.Var(m.Time, bounds=(0, battery.charging_power_limit * TIME_STEP_HOURS), initialize=0)
    m.posEInPV = en.Var(m.Time, bounds=(0, battery.charging_power_limit * TIME_STEP_HOURS), initialize=0)
    m.negEOutLocal = en.Var(m.Time, bounds=(battery.discharging_power_limit * TIME_STEP_HOURS, 0), initialize=0)
    m.negEOutExport = en.Var(m.Time, bounds=(battery.discharging_power_limit * TIME_STEP_HOURS, 0), initialize=0)
    m.posNetLoad = en.Var(m.Time, initialize=posLoadDict)
    m.negNetLoad = en.Var(m.Time, initialize=negLoadDict)
    m.Bool_char = en.Var(m.Time, within=en.Boolean)
    m.Bool_dis = en.Var(m.Time, within=en.Boolean, initialize=0)

    m.priceSell = en.Param(m.Time, initialize=priceDict1)
    m.priceBuy = en.Param(m.Time, initialize=priceDict2)
    m.posLoad = en.Param(m.Time, initialize=posLoadDict)
    m.negLoad = en.Param(m.Time, initialize=negLoadDict)
    m.etaChg = en.Param(initialize=battery.charging_efficiency)
    m.etaDisChg = en.Param(initialize=battery.discharging_efficiency)
    m.ChargingLimit = en.Param(initialize=battery.charging_power_limit * TIME_STEP_HOURS)
    m.DischargingLimit = en.Param(initialize=battery.discharging_power_limit * TIME_STEP_HOURS)

    def Obj_fn(m):
        return sum((m.priceBuy[t] * m.posNetLoad[t]) + (m.priceSell[t] * m.negNetLoad[t]) for t in m.Time)
    m.total_cost = en.Objective(rule=Obj_fn, sense=en.minimize)

    def SOC_rule(m, t):
        if t == 0:
            return m.SOC[t] == initial_soc + m.posDeltaSOC[t] + m.negDeltaSOC[t]
        return m.SOC[t] == m.SOC[t-1] + m.posDeltaSOC[t] + m.negDeltaSOC[t]
    m.Batt_SOC = en.Constraint(m.Time, rule=SOC_rule)

    def Bool_char_rule_1(m, t):
        return m.posDeltaSOC[t] >= -BIG_M * m.Bool_char[t]
    m.Batt_ch1 = en.Constraint(m.Time, rule=Bool_char_rule_1)

    def Bool_char_rule_2(m, t):
        return m.posDeltaSOC[t] <= 0 + BIG_M * (1 - m.Bool_dis[t])
    m.Batt_ch2 = en.Constraint(m.Time, rule=Bool_char_rule_2)

    def Bool_char_rule_3(m, t):
        return m.negDeltaSOC[t] <= BIG_M * m.Bool_dis[t]
    m.Batt_cd3 = en.Constraint(m.Time, rule=Bool_char_rule_3)

    def Bool_char_rule_4(m, t):
        return m.negDeltaSOC[t] >= 0 - BIG_M * (1 - m.Bool_char[t])
    m.Batt_cd4 = en.Constraint(m.Time, rule=Bool_char_rule_4)

    def Batt_char_dis(m, t):
        return m.Bool_char[t] + m.Bool_dis[t] <= 1
    m.Batt_char_dis = en.Constraint(m.Time, rule=Batt_char_dis)

    def pos_E_in_rule(m, t):
        return (m.posEInGrid[t] + m.posEInPV[t]) == m.posDeltaSOC[t] / m.etaChg
    m.posEIn_cons = en.Constraint(m.Time, rule=pos_E_in_rule)

    def neg_E_out_rule(m, t):
        return (m.negEOutLocal[t] + m.negEOutExport[t]) == m.negDeltaSOC[t] * m.etaDisChg
    m.negEOut_cons = en.Constraint(m.Time, rule=neg_E_out_rule)

    def E_charging_rate_rule(m, t):
        return (m.posEInGrid[t] + m.posEInPV[t]) <= m.ChargingLimit
    m.chargingLimit_cons = en.Constraint(m.Time, rule=E_charging_rate_rule)

    def E_discharging_rate_rule(m, t):
        return (m.negEOutLocal[t] + m.negEOutExport[t]) >= m.DischargingLimit
    m.dischargingLimit_cons = en.Constraint(m.Time, rule=E_discharging_rate_rule)

    def E_solar_charging_rule(m, t):
        return m.posEInPV[t] <= -m.negLoad[t]
    m.solarChargingLimit_cons = en.Constraint(m.Time, rule=E_solar_charging_rule)

    def E_local_discharge_rule(m, t):
        return m.negEOutLocal[t] >= -m.posLoad[t]
    m.localDischargingLimit_cons = en.Constraint(m.Time, rule=E_local_discharge_rule)

    def E_pos_net_rule(m, t):
        return m.posNetLoad[t] == m.posLoad[t] + m.posEInGrid[t] + m.negEOutLocal[t]
    m.E_posNet_cons = en.Constraint(m.Time, rule=E_pos_net_rule)

    def E_neg_net_rule(m, t):
        return m.negNetLoad[t] == m.negLoad[t] + m.posEInPV[t] + m.negEOutExport[t]
    m.E_negNet_cons = en.Constraint(m.Time, rule=E_neg_net_rule)

    opt = SolverFactory("glpk", executable=r"C:\Python\glpk-4.65\w64\glpsol.exe")
    t = time.time()
    results = opt.solve(m)
    elapsed = time.time() - t
    logging.info(f'Time elapsed for optimization: {elapsed} seconds')

    outputVars = np.zeros((9, len(sellPrice)))

    variable_indices = {
        'SOC': 0,
        'posDeltaSOC': 1,
        'negDeltaSOC': 2,
        'posEInGrid': 3,
        'posEInPV': 4,
        'negEOutLocal': 5,
        'negEOutExport': 6,
        'posNetLoad': 7,
        'negNetLoad': 8
    }

    for var_name, var_index in variable_indices.items():
        varobject = getattr(m, var_name)
        for index in varobject:
            if index < len(sellPrice):
                outputVars[var_index, index] = varobject[index].value

    final_soc = outputVars[0, -1]

    # Get the total cost for the current month
    cost_without_batt = round(np.sum([(buyPrice[i]*posLoad[i] + sellPrice[i]*negLoad[i]) for i in range(len(buyPrice))]))
    cost_with_batt = round(np.sum([(buyPrice[i]*outputVars[7, i] + sellPrice[i]*outputVars[8, i]) for i in range(len(buyPrice))]))

    # Calculate the score and money saved/earned for the current month
    score = (cost_with_batt - cost_without_batt) / np.abs(cost_without_batt) * 100
    money_saved = round(abs(cost_without_batt - cost_with_batt), 2)

    return outputVars, final_soc, cost_without_batt, cost_with_batt, score, money_saved

def main():
    """
    Main function to run the battery optimization for each month of the year.
    """
    full_output = []
    initial_soc = Binitial_soc

    total_cost_without_batt = 0
    total_cost_with_batt = 0
    total_score = 0
    total_money_saved = 0

    for month in range(1, 13):
        start_date = pd.Timestamp(year=2023, month=month, day=1)
        end_date = start_date + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0) + pd.Timedelta(hours=23.5)
        logging.info(f"Running optimization from {start_date.strftime(' %D %Y %H:%M ')} to {end_date.strftime(' %D %Y %H:%M ')}")
        monthly_output, initial_soc, cost_without_batt, cost_with_batt, score, money_saved = run_monthly_optimization(start_date, end_date, initial_soc)
        full_output.append(monthly_output)

        total_cost_without_batt += cost_without_batt
        total_cost_with_batt += cost_with_batt
        total_score = (total_cost_with_batt - total_cost_without_batt) / np.abs(total_cost_without_batt) * 100
        total_money_saved += money_saved

        logging.info(f"Cost without battery for {start_date.strftime('%B %Y')}: £{cost_without_batt}")
        logging.info(f"Cost with battery for {start_date.strftime('%B %Y')}: £{cost_with_batt}")
        logging.info(f"Score for {start_date.strftime('%B %Y')}: {score:.4f}%")
        logging.info(f"Money saved/earned for {start_date.strftime('%B %Y')}: £{money_saved}")

    # Print the total results for the entire year
    logging.info(f'Total cost without battery for the entire year: £{total_cost_without_batt}')
    logging.info(f'Total cost with battery for the entire year: £{total_cost_with_batt}')
    logging.info(f'Total score for the entire year: {total_score:.4f}%')
    logging.info(f'Total money saved/earned for the entire year: £{total_money_saved}')

    # Concatenate results from all months
    full_output = np.concatenate(full_output, axis=1)

    # Create datetime index
    time_index = pd.date_range(start=g_df.index.min(), periods=len(full_output[0]), freq='30min')
    timeDF = pd.DataFrame(index=time_index)
    timeDF['demand'] = g_df['demand'].values[:len(full_output[0])]
    timeDF['pv'] = g_df['generation'].values[:len(full_output[0])]
    timeDF['buyPrice'] = g_df['buyPrice'].values[:len(full_output[0])]
    timeDF['sellPrice'] = g_df['sellPrice'].values[:len(full_output[0])]

    # Export results to CSV
    headers = ['SOC', 'posDeltaSOC', 'negDeltaSOC', 'posEInGrid', 'posEInPV', 'negEOutLocal', 'negEOutExport', 'posNetLoad', 'negNetLoad']
    outputDF = pd.DataFrame(full_output.T, columns=headers, index=time_index)

    outputDF = pd.concat([timeDF, outputDF], axis=1)
    outputDF.to_csv("full_output.csv")
    logging.info("Optimization results saved to full_output.csv")

    plot_results(outputDF, full_output)
    plot_new_daily_profiles(outputDF, sns.color_palette())

def plot_results(outputDF, full_output):
    """
    Plot the results of the optimization.
    """
    newNetLoad = full_output[7] + full_output[8]
    colors = sns.color_palette()

    # Convert the index to a datetime format for plotting
    outputDF['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(outputDF.index)

    fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(14, 12))

    # Plot demand, PV, and net load with storage
    ax1.plot(outputDF['datetime'], outputDF['demand'], color=colors[0], label='Demand')
    ax1.plot(outputDF['datetime'], outputDF['pv'], color=colors[1], label='PV')
    ax1.plot(outputDF['datetime'], newNetLoad, color=colors[3], label='With storage')
    ax1.set_xlabel('Date')
    ax1.set_ylabel('kWh')
    ax1.legend(ncol=3)
    ax1.set_xlim([outputDF['datetime'].min(), outputDF['datetime'].max()])
    ax1.set_title('Demand, PV, and Net Load with Storage')

    # Plot buy and sell prices
    ax2.plot(outputDF['datetime'], outputDF['buyPrice'], color=colors[3], label='Buy Price')
    ax2.plot(outputDF['datetime'], outputDF['sellPrice'], color=colors[4], label='Sell Price')
    ax2.set_xlabel('Date')
    ax2.set_ylabel('Price')
    ax2.legend(ncol=2)
    ax2.set_xlim([outputDF['datetime'].min(), outputDF['datetime'].max()])
    ax2.set_title('Buy and Sell Prices')

    # Plot battery action and SOC
    ax3.plot(outputDF['datetime'], np.sum(full_output[3:7, :], axis=0), color=colors[5], label='Battery action (kWh)')
    ax3.plot(outputDF['datetime'], full_output[0], color=colors[4], label='SOC (kWh)')
    ax3.set_xlabel('Date')
    ax3.set_ylabel('Action')
    ax3.legend(ncol=2)
    ax3.set_xlim([outputDF['datetime'].min(), outputDF['datetime'].max()])
    ax3.set_title('Battery Action and SOC')

    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

    plot_daily_profiles(outputDF, colors)

def plot_daily_profiles(outputDF, colors):
    """
    Plot daily profiles of the optimization results.
    """
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 8))

    # Resample to daily averages
    daily_df = outputDF.drop(columns=['datetime']).resample('D').sum()

    ax1.plot(daily_df.index, daily_df['demand'], color=colors[0], label='Demand')
    ax1.plot(daily_df.index, daily_df['pv'], color=colors[1], label='PV')
    ax1.plot(daily_df.index, (daily_df['posNetLoad'] + daily_df['negNetLoad']), color=colors[3], label='With storage')
    ax1.set_xlabel('Date')
    ax1.set_ylabel('kWh')
    ax1.legend(ncol=3)
    ax1.set_xlim([daily_df.index.min(), daily_df.index.max()])
    ax1.set_title('Daily Demand, PV, and Net Load with Storage')

    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()


def plot_new_daily_profiles(outputDF, colors):
    """
    Plot a new daily profile with demand as a line and stacked areas for imports, PV to demand, battery to demand,
    and negative stacked areas for exports.
    """
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 8))

    # Resample to daily sums
    daily_df = outputDF.drop(columns=['datetime']).resample('D').sum()

    # Calculate the daily import, PV to demand, battery to demand, and exports
    daily_df['pv_to_demand'] = daily_df['pv'] + daily_df['negNetLoad'] - daily_df['posEInPV']
    daily_df['import_to_meet_demand'] = daily_df['posNetLoad'] - daily_df['posEInGrid']
    daily_df['battery_to_demand'] = -daily_df['negEOutLocal']
    daily_df['import_to_battery'] = daily_df['posEInGrid']  

    daily_df['total_demand'] = daily_df['demand']
    
    daily_df['export_pv_to_grid'] = daily_df['negNetLoad']
    daily_df['export_battery_to_grid'] = daily_df['negEOutExport']

    # Plot the total demand as a line
    ax.plot(daily_df.index, daily_df['total_demand'], color=colors[0], label='Total Demand', linewidth=2)

    # Plot the positive stacked areas
    ax.fill_between(daily_df.index, 0, daily_df['import_to_meet_demand'], color=colors[1], label='Import to Meet Demand')
    ax.fill_between(daily_df.index, daily_df['import_to_meet_demand'], daily_df['import_to_meet_demand'] + daily_df['pv_to_demand'], color=colors[2], label='PV to Demand')
    ax.fill_between(daily_df.index, daily_df['import_to_meet_demand'] + daily_df['pv_to_demand'], daily_df['import_to_meet_demand'] + daily_df['pv_to_demand'] + daily_df['battery_to_demand'], color=colors[3], label='Battery to Demand')

    # Plot the negative stacked areas below the x-axis
    ax.fill_between(daily_df.index, 0, daily_df['export_battery_to_grid'], color=colors[4], label='Battery Export')
    ax.fill_between(daily_df.index, daily_df['export_battery_to_grid'], daily_df['export_battery_to_grid'] + daily_df['export_pv_to_grid'], color=colors[5], label='PV to Grid')

    # Formatting the plot
    ax.set_xlabel('Date', fontsize=12)
    ax.set_ylabel('Energy (kWh)', fontsize=12)
    ax.set_title('Daily Energy Balance with Demand and Storage', fontsize=14)
    ax.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize=10)

    # Optionally, add data labels to stacked areas
    # for i in range(len(daily_df)):
    #     ax.text(daily_df.index[i], daily_df['import_to_meet_demand'][i] / 2, f"{daily_df['import_to_meet_demand'][i]:.1f}", ha='center', va='center', fontsize=8, color='white')
    #     ax.text(daily_df.index[i], daily_df['import_to_meet_demand'][i] + daily_df['pv_to_demand'][i] / 2, f"{daily_df['pv_to_demand'][i]:.1f}", ha='center', va='center', fontsize=8, color='white')
    #     ax.text(daily_df.index[i], daily_df['import_to_meet_demand'][i] + daily_df['pv_to_demand'][i] + daily_df['battery_to_demand'][i] / 2, f"{daily_df['battery_to_demand'][i]:.1f}", ha='center', va='center', fontsize=8, color='white')

    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()





if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I've tried many things, but im not sure if I've been implementing them properly.

This isn't a full answer, but too long for comment...
I'm not sure your base model is working well.  You aren't checking for optimal solve after the solve.  When I chop your data down to just the very first 4 entries, the model is unbounded, so something is amiss.
Consider editing your code around the solve to doing this (glpk part is fine, I just use CBC):
m.pprint()

# opt = SolverFactory("glpk", executable=r"C:\Program Files\glpk-4.65\w64\glpsol.exe")
opt = SolverFactory('cbc')
t = time.time()
results = opt.solve(m)
if not check_optimal_termination(results=results):
    print('non-optimal termination')
    sys.exit(-1)

Then, make a copy of your data and chop it down to the first 4 values.  I think that should solve, but it doesn't.  Perhaps some of your variables should be NonNegativeReals?
I also don't understand your balance of power equations.  There seems to be too many moving parts, but troubleshooting with small data may help with that.
